# How to manage response from paypal when people pay as a guest checkout. No paypal account

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using a custom php Paypal nvp API for express checkout.
When people pay with their paypal account I have no problem in my php script, I insert the order, order details and I send the email to the customer. When people pay with their credit card without paypal account I don't receive the transactionid.
The strange fact is that when I use the sandbox, I generate a fake visa I do the payment, in my database I have the transaction id and I receive the email.
Someone had or is having my same problem?
There are different ways to manage payment with and without account?
For both I'm checking the payment status = Complete.

Comment: It's possible this is lack of concreteness, but let's hope i am wrong. Perhaps someone who already use express checkout will answer. Have you check what payment method you looking for in the documentation? Usually it already have commonly used example.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'm trying to investigare with IPN payment notification. But with the sandbox everything is running with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to help your query,

Firstly, PayPal NVP is deprecated implementation. There wouldn't any support for new merchants who willing to add PayPal as a payment option.

Please go through the below recent products which run on REST APIs. I suggested two options of accepting payments so, hence choose the best one suits you.

1. Standard Integration [Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/).
2. Advanced Credit & Debit Card [Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks very much. I know is deprecated, but now the ecommerce is done. My problem is that when people pay with crefit card without account, sonetime I don't receive the transito. I insert in the database and send email only after the check Paymentinfo_0_PAYMENTSTATUS is completed. I'm trying with IPN to debug.

Comment: Yes, you can use IPN to verify the payment status.

Comment: I solved the problem. Apparently it was a mix of problems. When the response come back from paypal in my success page it happens a double insert in the db. So the problem was not paypal. Thanks everyone for the help.